# generate an editable file (e.g. odt) from my latex sources for editor

Tags: pdf

The document I am writing has many tex files. I want to give my editor a copy of the document. The copy may not be a pdf because the editor wants/needs to edit the document (spelling, grammar) and is not common with tex at all.

How can I create a (e.g. odt) from my latex sources?

Comment: You can import your pdf in Libre / Open Office and it will get comverted. How good the conversion is, depends on the complexity of your document.

Comment: You can try with pandoc (http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/index.html)

Comment: Unless you don't want to work again on your latex source files, I don't think it is a good idea to «convert» them so that someone edits the converted file, because you will have to 1) find out what —and how and why— was edited and 2) rewrite these corrections on your source tex files. It is a lot easier if your editor points out a comment on a PDF regarding what has to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no perfect solution. Best is told to be Adobe used to save a PDF generated from LaTeX.

Some example approaches here never the less …

### challenging setup

Found a solution on https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1033441

That might be good enough for the mentioned purpose but problems remain.

### conversion via HTML

More solid should be

```
latex2html texfile.tex -split 0 -no_navigation -info "" -address "" -html_version 4.0,unicode
libreoffice --headless --convert-to odt:"OpenDocument Text Flat XML" texfile/index.html
```

### conversion with pandoc

```
pandoc -f latex -t odt -o output.odt input.tex
```

Comment: You can convert to ODT using tex4ht. This is what I do, but you don't want to have to reintegrate the changes, as mentioned above.

Comment: well, if people want to make changes for error correction this way it is AFAIK better than printing on paper and color/mark that with pen and noteits ;) – unfortunately not everyone uses git even on the quite user friendly web platforms

Comment: I doubt git would help, though I don't use it. But the point stands, as discussed above. PDF is the best option really. But tex4ht is better at converting than other things I've tried.